# What is the most practical way of finding the particular solution of this differential equation (RLC circuit)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The RLC circuit forms the following differential equation:

$$\frac{di^2}{dt^2}+a_1\frac{di}{dt}+a_0i=k\cos{(wt+f)}$$

Assuming the roots of the characteristic equation are complex, complimentary function becomes:

$$i_c=e^{\alpha t}\left[ c_1\cos{\beta t} + c_2\sin{\beta t} \right]
 $$

So far, I tried "*undetermined coefficients*", "*variation of parameters*" and "*solution by the use of complex variables*" methods to find the **particular solution** $i_p$. However, things get messy for all of them and I can't find the particular solution.

Can you please show me the most practical way of finding the particular solution? Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of Laplace transform?

Comment: @TroyWoo There is no initial conditions. Additionaly, I don't want to use Laplace transform. It is also a circuit analysis method. I have been studying diff. equations for one month. I want to make use of it.

Comment: You will have to provide initial conditions...otherwise there is no method that can produce one for you...

Comment: @TroyWoo I know.

Comment: Judging from what you said, you meant that the absence of initial conditions stops you from applying Laplace transformation, which is ridiculous. I think it would be helpful if you explain your logic here.

Comment: @TroyWoo As I said, I am trying to make use of my diff. equation knowledge. If I had known I couldn't solve this without Laplace transform, I would just study circuit analysis which use Laplace transforms extensively. I agree it may sound ridiculous but I am obsessed about a solution without Laplace transform.

Comment: @Amzoti Finally I found the correct solution with UC. The constants contain additional terms (like $1/LC$) therefore I was confused during the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct solution using "*undetermined coefficients*" method. It is more practical than "*variation of parameters*" and "*solution by the use of complex variables*" methods. Still this method doesn't look tempting. Here is what I found:

$$\boxed{i_p=A\cos(wt+f)+B\sin(wt+f)}$$

$$i^\prime_p=-wA\sin(wt+f)+wB\cos(wt+f)$$

$$i^{\prime \prime}_p=-w^2A\cos(wt+f)-w^2B\sin(wt+f)$$

Putting these into the equation:

$$-w^2A\cos(wt+f)-w^2B\sin(wt+f)-a_1wA\sin(wt+f)+a_1wB\cos(wt+f)+a_0A\\\cos(wt+f)+a_0B\sin(wt+f)=k\cos(wt+f)$$

$$\left[ (a_0-w^2)A+a_1wB \right]\cos(wt+f)+\left[ (a_0-w^2)B-a_1wA \right]\sin(wt+f)=k\cos(wt+f)$$

Finding the values of $A$ and $B$ is the most error-prone part. If you are not a mathematician and you are rusty on such operations you can struggle for 5 hours like me :). The correct reults are:

$$A=\frac{k(a_0-w^2)}{(a_0-w^2)^2+a_1^2w^2}\;\;and\;\;B=\frac{ka_1w}{(a_0-w^2)^2+a_1^2w^2}$$